# DRBD with primary-to-primary as a RAID1 over TCP/IP with both notes read/write?

Tags: raid, ubuntu-10.04, drbd

In my setup I have two machines. Both of them have almost the same setup, except for the amount of RAM. On both sides I want to designate `/dev/sdb1` as the underlying device for a common `/dev/drbd0`.

As I understand it (please correct me if I'm wrong) primary-to-primary is the way to go when I want to be able to write to the resulting `/dev/drbd0` *from both machines*. However, performance is not my biggest concern here. The important thing is that no extra effort (such as rsync) is required to keep them in sync.

Now, reading the documentation I got confused as to whether a clustering file system (such as GFS) goes on top of that device or has to be (somehow?!) layered underneath the `/dev/drbd0`. Can someone shed light on that?

I'd also like to know what solution is generally preferred for such a scenario.

NB: If you can recommend alternatives to DRBD, feel free to name them and provide pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to format that device with a filesystem that is cluster aware and one that uses a distributed lock manager (such as GFS.)  So GFS would be on top of the drbd device.

Comment: Okay, so the GFS goes on top of the DRBD and can then be used from both ends? Thank you.